# Panel Drawing User Controls

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I am currently working on a project, and for security purposes, I don't want the user having multiple windows open. I want their entire experience with the system to be encapsulated within one window. I tried a few different ways, but the only one that seems like it will work is having a Panel that draws in UserControls. I have a panel on my Main_Menu called pnlMain. I can get it to draw the first UserControl, MainMenuPanel. What I can trying to do is, when I click a button in MainMenuPanel, it clears pnlMain in Main_Menu, and draws in another UserControl called PartsSystem, and then go in layers from there.

Is there any way to do this?

Whenever I try, I get: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Null reference exception)

Comment: Any reason you can't use a tab control and just have your views as different tabs?

Comment: This would be better on superuser.com

Comment: Not sure how to work those without having all the tabs I'll ever use up at once. Like, when they click on Parts Inventory, I wanted it to take them to the Parts Inventory screen. If there was a way to hide the tab bar entirely so they couldn't click between them or even see them, that would work. Otherwise, it's outside of the design specs I was given.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why can't the user have more than one Window open? Which is the security concern? Why not close current Window when opening new one?